# This code in game maker won't work properly:

Tags: game-maker, gml

---

**This code does destroy the object when its health reaches 0 but it won't add 5/7 to the global.xp variable.**

```
if rotem_hp > 1 and shop_13 = 0
{   
rotem_hp = rotem_hp -1
}
else
{
if rotem_hp > 1 and shop_13 = 1 rotem_hp = rotem_hp -1.5
if rotem_hp < 1 and shop_4 = 0 global.xp = global.xp + 5 instance_destroy()
if rotem_hp < 1 and shop_4 = 1 global.xp = global.xp + 7 instance_destroy()
}
```

---

### This wont work either

```
if (rotem_hp > 1 and global.shop_13 = 0)
{   
rotem_hp = rotem_hp -1
}
else if (rotem_hp > 1 and global.shop_13 = 1) 
{
rotem_hp = rotem_hp -1.5
}
else if (rotem_hp < 1 and global.shop_4 = 0) 
{
global.xp = global.xp +5 
instance_destroy()
}
else if (rotem_hp < 1 and global.shop_4 = 1)
{
global.xp = global.xp +7 
instance_destroy()
}
else
{
//do nothing
}
```

---

### This wont destroy the object  (btw in create event i have (rotem_hp = 5)

```
if rotem_hp > 1 and global.shop_13 = 0
{
rotem_hp = rotem_hp -1 
}

if rotem_hp > 1 and global.shop_13 = 1
{
rotem_hp = rotem_hp -1.5
}

if rotem_hp < 1 and global.shop_4 = 0
{
global.xp = global.xp +5 
instance_destroy()
}

if rotem_hp < 1 and global.shop_4 = 1
{
global.xp = global.xp +7
instance_destroy()
}
```

I will appreciate any efforts to answer my question.

Comment: You can update your answer to include the code added as a comment

Comment: What problem? What you want? And what is `shop_13` and `shop_4`? What event you used?

Comment: Global.shop variables are stuff that when I buy in the shop something it sets its variable to 1 instead of 0 as it is true (Boolean or something).

Comment: It give stuff like added damage or xp as you can see

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
if rotem_hp < 1 and shop_4 = 0 global.xp = global.xp + 5 instance_destroy()
if rotem_hp < 1 and shop_4 = 1 global.xp = global.xp + 7 instance_destroy()
```

it means

```
if rotem_hp < 1 and shop_4 = 0
{
    global.xp = global.xp + 5
}
instance_destroy()

if rotem_hp < 1 and shop_4 = 1 
{
    global.xp = global.xp + 7
}
instance_destroy()
```

so last `if` will newer checked bacause the object will be already destroyed.
You need use curve braces for define `if` scopes.

You can write like this:

```
if rotem_hp < 1 and shop_4 = 0
{
    global.xp += 5
    instance_destroy()
}

if rotem_hp < 1 and shop_4 = 1 
{
    global.xp += 7
    instance_destroy()
}
```

or if you want only one line for one 'if'

```
if rotem_hp < 1 and shop_4 = 0 { global.xp += 5; instance_destroy(); }
if rotem_hp < 1 and shop_4 = 1 { global.xp += 7; instance_destroy(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for everyone who encountered the same problem as me:

I finally managed to solve the issue, the problem was that I used:

```
if rotem_hp > 1
{   
rotem_hp = rotem_hp -1
}
```

Instead of:

```
if rotem_hp >= 1
{   
rotem_hp = rotem_hp -1
}
```

So when "rotem"'s health reachd exactly 1, the code didnt know what to do since I told it to do stuff when >1 and <1, this was such a stupid problem and I cant believe I wasted more than a few minutes to solve it, I will now go hide in the corner of my room full  with shame. goodbye.